# Convert string into vector

Tags: r, stringr

How can I convert this string into a vector? 
`"c(HJ229, HJ230, HJ231)"` 
The desired result is `"HJ229" "HJ230" "HJ231"`.

I have tried using `stringr`, however the `(` causes an issue because of regex.

```
t <- "c(HJ229, HJ230, HJ231)"

strsplit(str_remove(t, "c"), "(")[[1]]
```

Comment: That looks like an R expression, suggesting that what you are doing here is repairing a previous operation that inadvertently combined things in a way you did not want. If that's true, I suggest you fix the previous problem and do it *correctly* vice trying to repair it in this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that will work. This structure is a result of needing multiple characters in the same column as a description in a neighboring row. I need to be able to access the contents of this column in R for further analysis but I also need to tidy spreadsheet my supervising, who does not code, can view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(stringr)

s <-"c(HJ229, HJ230, HJ231)" 
str_extract_all(s, "[A-Z]{2}\\d{3}")[[1]]

#> [1] "HJ229" "HJ230" "HJ231"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the parentheses to remove them with `regex` using `\\` and provide multiple patterns to match separated by `|` (or).

```r
library(stringr)

t <- "c(HJ229, HJ230, HJ231)"

str_split(str_remove_all(t, "c|\\(|\\)"), ", ")[[1]]
#> [1] "HJ229" "HJ230" "HJ231"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using base `R`:

```
t = "c(HJ229, HJ230, HJ231)"
strsplit(gsub("[c()]", "", t), ", ")[[1]]

[1] "HJ229" "HJ230" "HJ231"
```

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_split(str_remove_all(t, "[c()]"), ", ")[[1]]

[1] "HJ229" "HJ230" "HJ231"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
> scan(text = gsub("c\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", s), what = "", quiet = TRUE, sep = ",")
[1] "HJ229"  " HJ230" " HJ231"
```